# Neighbor using my property

Tags: trespass

I have a parcel in Ohio and use to own the house next to it. I lost my home and someone bought it but I still own parcel which I paid 10,000.00 25 years ago. I live out of state but have offered to sell for 4,000.00 to owners of my old house. They won't buy it because they use it. I have put up no trespass signs and they rip them down. I put them back up but they mow my lawn so they can use it. They have a swing set on it and a child's plastic playhouse. They put a fire pit in the middle of my property. What can I file in the courts? I have asked several times to have them remove swing set and quit mowing but they continue.

Comment: Have they been acting as owners for the whole 25 years?  As the current answer says, eventually if you aren't making any claims in court about it and they've been taking care of it, it becomes their land, and 25 years would be beyond that point.

Comment: As it's s civil matter, you may be able to find low cost legal help, even though you live in a different state. Google "free legal aid" in your area.

Comment: How did you lose your home? Foreclosure?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to hire an attorney to sue them. They have adversely taken possession of your land, which means that after a period of time they own your land, unless you take legal action. The time period in Ohio is 21 years. An alternative is to grant them revocable permission to use your land, but since they seem disinclined to give up the land, you will ultimately have to take this matter to court.

Comment: How do you figure they've possessed the land for 21 years?

Comment: @bdb484 He hasn't.  He's stated a legal fact for Ohio, and made no assertions about its applicability to the OP's situation (as the OP has not specified this), other than the implicit assertion that the OP is on a timer and should act before it's up.

Comment: Hiring an attorney is a good idea, but sometimes a letter from an attorney will be just as effective as a lawsuit, and it's cheaper. It sounds like the poster would like to sell the parcel, so that would be an effective resolution,

Comment: @zibadawatimmy "They have adversely taken possession of your land" seems to be an assertion of applicability to the OP's situation.

Comment: Most attorneys need to be hired to write letters, but there could be exceptions. I admit that the scope of "to sue" is about the owner's ultimate legal recourse, and doesn't mean that a well-worded letter wouldn't do the trick, maybe. Adverse possession exists well before 21 years has passed.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate. Adverse possession is "the doctrine by which *title to real property is acquired* as a result of ... use or enjoyment over a specified period of time." Black's, 10th ed. Until the adverse party acquires title, simply occupying the land would just be called trespassing.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want an attorney for this one. Unless they've been occupying the land for 21+ years, which seems unlikely since you bought it 25 years ago, they probably aren't legally entitled to the land.

However, the police are probably unlikely to get involved, for two reasons:

1. This is a mostly civil matter and police don't like getting wrapped up in boundary disputes.
2. The current property owner is the daughter of a member of city council.

There are a variety of mechanisms for pursuing legal action, but you'll be up against someone with both money and political clout. Attempting to do this on your own would be ill-advised.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you gt the "duaghter of a member of city council" from?  I don't see that anywhere else.

Comment: After seeing the OP's name, I realized I grew up just a few miles away from the parcel of land we're talking about.